# Hyperparameter tunning in SelectKBest feature selector

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, dataset, scikit-learn

I am working with a pretty large dataset containing 760 rows and arround 58k-60k features and I'd like to perform a feature selection to reduce the dimensionality of those. After stardardising the data I've decide to try with the SelectKBest method from sklearn and I realized that I have to provide a number of features I want to select (named k).

Is there any way of tunning this k parameter? How can I know the proper amount of features to select out of the almost 60k that I have initially?

The dataset contains different cancer patients' genes expressions by the way. Each column is a different gene, that's why I have so many features.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should look at some kind of regularization. Is likely those algorithms don't choose all important variables or choose wrong ones. Look at this
http://www.danielezrajohnson.com/stepwise.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SelectKBest, I will assume you are using the data for a prediction problem. You could split your data into train-validation-test sets or use a train-test split with [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) on the training set.
Then you can try different $k$ for feature selection and compare the performance on the validation set, for example by plotting accuracy against k. That should give you an idea about the trade-off between the number of features and predictive performance.

Comment: I made more research about the problem I was trying to resolve and I saw that It was too easy for a ML model to solve it and at the end it didn't matter much how much features I select. But I'll take it into account for the future, thanks!